# How can I detect what functions the linker omits in a release build using VC10?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using Visual C++ 2010 (Service Pack 1), is there a way I can get the linker to output the functions it has discarded (are not called) in a release mode X64 build?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.  You can do the opposite, however; the option
`/Fmfilename`, when passed to `cl`, will cause the
linker to output a map; if you invoke the linker directly, the option is
`/MAP:filename`.  (In both cases, you can omit the
filename.)  This will give you a list of all of the functions (and other
symbols) in the executable.

After the link, you can still recover a certain amount of information
(depending on the link options) by using `dumpbin`.